# Convert shape size to cm

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have VBA code for changing size of shapes, but I want to convert the number to be in cm. Any suggestion for how to convert these numbers?
Another question is that I want to change the same size for multiple selected shapes; can you help me with this as well?

Thank you very much!

```
Sub test()
    Dim objHeigh As Integer
    Dim objWidth As Integer
    Dim oSh As Shape

    On Error GoTo CheckErrors

    With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
        If .Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox "You need to select a shape first"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    For Each oSh In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
        objHeigh = oSh.Height
        objWidth = oSh.Width

        objHeigh = CInt(InputBox$("Assign a new size of Height", "Heigh", objHeigh))
        ' give the user a way out
        If objHeigh = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If objName <> "" Then
            oSh.Name = objName
        End If

        objWidth = CInt(InputBox$("Assign a new size of Width", "Width", objWidth))
        ' give the user a way out
        If objWidth = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        oSh.Height = CInt(objHeigh)
        oSh.Width = CInt(objWidth)
    Next
    Exit Sub

    CheckErrors: MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744642.aspx), the height / width of the corresponding shape properties are specified in points:

> Returns or sets the height of the specified object, in points.
>   Read/write.

and on that page they specifically show an example and referring to the fact, that 1 inch has 72 points

> This example sets the height for row two in the specified table to 100
>   points (72 points per inch).

Therefore I guess it is safe to rely on that fact and just write a function to convert it yourself:

```
Function ConvertPointToCm(ByVal pnt As Double) As Double
    ConvertPointToCm = pnt * 0.03527778
End Function

Function ConvertCmToPoint(ByVal cm As Double) As Double
    ConvertCmToPoint = cm * 28.34646
End Function
```

---

As far as your question with sizing multiple objects is concerned, I am not sure if I understand your problem fully. I interpreted it in a way so that moving your prompts to the user out of the `For` loop should give you the desired result (if that is in fact your desired result :)):

```
objHeigh = CInt(InputBox$("Assign a new size of Height", "Heigh"))
' give the user a way out
If objHeigh = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
End If
objHeigh = ConvertCmToPoint(objHeigh)

objWidth = CInt(InputBox$("Assign a new size of Width", "Width"))
' give the user a way out
If objWidth = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
End If
objWidth = ConvertCmToPoint(objWidth)

For Each oSh In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    If objName <> "" Then
        oSh.Name = objName
    End If

    oSh.Height = CInt(objHeigh)
    oSh.Width = CInt(objWidth)
Next
```

Comment: Ok thank you. But where should I assign that function in my code?

Comment: Put it .e.g in the same module as your test() sub and then you can call it like ConvertCmToPoint(10.5). So basically you can copy & paste the functions below your "end sub" line of your initial code

Comment: Yes I know that. Sorry since Im new with VBA Im confused where to call that function, should I assign to the variable or? Thanks for your effort!

Comment: You can call it e.g. after you check them for 0. I updated my answer to reflect that.